# Moving JInternalFrames from one JDesktopPane to another

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe, jdesktoppane

I have been designing a Swing-based tabletop RPG program to facilitate text-based roleplay with GUI control elements.

To facilitate this, each running client gets a main desktop ("GM Desktop" on the hosting client and "Player Desktop" on the remote clients) with all of the important JFrames. Additionally, both GM and Players can open "Perspective Desktops" for characters, providing them with a separate JDesktopPane that contains the "Role Play Chat Window" that gives that character's perspective, along with additional JInternalFrames such as the "Character Sheet Window", etc.

The user navigates between desktops using a JTabbedPane.

The issue that I am having is that SOME of the windows I want to be able to move between desktops. For example, if the OOC (Out-of-Character) Chat receives a message while the user is in a Perspective Desktop, I want there to be an option for the OOC Chat Window to automatically relocate to the current desktop so the user sees the message immediately. Similarly I want the player to be able to "call" certain windows into the current desktop using the menu bar.

However, when I attempt to move a JInternalFrame from one JDesktopPane to another, I receive an exception.

```
com.finnickslab.textroleplayonline.exceptions.CommandEventHandlingException
An exception was thrown during command handling. CommandEvent type: UI_OOC_CHAT (26).
Cause Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
illegal component position
java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
javax.swing.JLayeredPane.addImpl(Unknown Source)
javax.swing.JDesktopPane.addImpl(Unknown Source)
java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
com.finnickslab.textroleplayonline.ui.GameDesktop.receiveTransfer(GameDesktop.java:80)
com.finnickslab.textroleplayonline.ui.GameDesktop.access$0(GameDesktop.java:74)
com.finnickslab.textroleplayonline.ui.GameDesktop$2.run(GameDesktop.java:69)
com.finnickslab.textroleplayonline.ui.UI.invokeEvent(UI.java:818)
com.finnickslab.textroleplayonline.ui.GameDesktop.transfer(GameDesktop.java:62)
com.finnickslab.textroleplayonline.ui.UI$HostCommandHandler.handle(UI.java:605)
com.finnickslab.textroleplayonline.comm.Server$3.run(Server.java:324)
```

All JInternalFrames in my program descend from the same subclass of JInternalFrame ("InternalWindow").

The exception makes it look a little convoluted but it boils down to calling JDesktopPane.remove(JInternalFrame) then JDesktopPane.add(JInternalFrame).

And then I receive that exception as soon as the "add" method is called on GameDesktop line 80.

```
/**
 * Transfers the specified InternalWindow from this GameDesktop to
 * the specified GameDesktop. Use this method to prevent
 * automatic removal of listeners performed with the
 * {@link GameDesktop.remove(InternalWindow)} method.
 */
public synchronized void transfer(
      final InternalWindow window,
      final GameDesktop gd) {
   final GameDesktop desktop = this;
   contents.remove(window);

   UI.invokeEvent(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
         desktop.remove((JInternalFrame) window);
         desktop.validate();
         desktop.repaint();

         gd.receiveTransfer(window);
      }
   });
}

private synchronized void receiveTransfer(InternalWindow window) {
   contents.add(window);

   window.changeDesktop(this);
   window.center();
   this.add((JInternalFrame) window);    // LINE 80
   this.validate();
   this.repaint();
   window.resetPosition();
}
```

The "UI.invokeEvent(Runnable)" method is a convenience method I wrote for SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(Runnable). It checks to see if the current thread is the EDT and, if it is, executes the run() method immediately. Otherwise, it uses invokeAndWait(Runnable) to schedule the runnable on the EDT.

Any ideas of how to fix this problem would be appreciated.

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]

EDIT:

All my research on this error suggests that it has something to do with the Z-axis position of the component. I tried changing the add call to specify the z position

```
super.add(window, getComponentCount());
```

but no change. Still getting the same IllegalArgumentException.

Comment: Try your code with the 2 desktop panes on the same thread. It's hard to see from your code if it's a synchronization issue or something local.

Comment: They are being called on the same thread: The EDT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if you get the same error when running this. If not, the problem is not with switching the parent of the internal frame, it's with the synchronization.

```
public class IFSwitch extends JDesktopPane {

    final JDesktopPane pane1 = this;

    public IFSwitch() {

        JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Frame1");
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Frame2");
//      JDesktopPane pane1 = new JDesktopPane();
        JDesktopPane pane2 = new JDesktopPane();
        final JInternalFrame if1 = new JInternalFrame();

        frame1.add(pane1);
        frame2.add(pane2);
        pane1.add(if1);

        if1.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 100);
        frame1.setBounds(100, 100, 200, 200);
        frame2.setBounds(500, 500, 200, 200);
        frame1.setVisible(true);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
        if1.setVisible(true);

        try {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        pane2.add(if1);
        pane1.remove(if1); // You don't even need this line.
        pane1.repaint();

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new IFSwitch();
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how this is any different from my code. The add and remove methods are both being called on the EventDispatchThread, from inside the run() method on the anonymous inner class. run() calls 'remove(JInternalFrame)' and then calls 'receiveTransfer(InternalWindow)' wherein the 'add(InternalFrame)' method is called.

You might be getting hung up on the 'contents.remove()' and 'contents.add()' calls. 'contents' is simply an ArrayList of InternalFrames that the GameDesktop uses when the 'showAll()' method is called.

Comment: @SeanThomas Well, if it is not different, how is it that my code works and yours doesn't? You say you get an error when removing the internal frame from one desktop pane and adding it to another. Check what you're doing different.

Comment: Honestly you may be right and it WAS a synchronization issue. I'm not incredibly experienced with multi-threading. I did however, solve the problem, although I don't really know how. I combined the "transfer" and "receiveTransfer" methods, so now I call "transfer(InternalWindow)" on the RECEIVING desktop. Suddenly it started working.

I didn't know that a private field of one object can be accessed by the another object of the same class. Once I found out that I could directly remove the window from the contents list of the previous desktop, I combined the two methods and it started working.

Comment: @SeanThomas Concurrency is one of *the* most difficult subjects in any programing language. It requires meticulousness, knowledge in several fields, and it's between hard to impossible to debug. Once I knew that without concurrency (and the need to synchronize) the code works, it was safe to assume that that was the problem.